# Docker left Promiscious mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vmware, docker-swarm, bridge

I have a VM with a docker running, on dmesg i see somme errors: `Messages “promiscuous mode” entered & left`

Can you help me to resolve the issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, but normal activity for a Docker container host as container interfaces are created and destroyed.

There's a short description on a [github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14807#issuecomment-123366926) as to what is happening. My understanding of this explanation is that promiscuous mode is required for traffic to flow from the bridge on the host through the virtual interface interface on the host and into the corresponding virtual interface in the container. This is necessary to put the host-side virtual interface into promiscuous mode because it has a different mac address than the container's virtual interface. Promiscuous mode allows the traffic to pass through that link into the container. This applies to the Docker "bridge" and "overlay" network drivers since they both use a linux bridge interface in their implementation.

You can safely ignore these messages in the output of `dmesg`.